# How does Synaptic have updates when I've just updated from the command line?

Tags: apt

How can that be?  I thought the CLI was the nuts (that's a good thing).  I go there (Ctrl + Alt + F1) and:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get check
```

All's well.

Go back to the GUI and open Synaptic Package Manager and:

1. Reload
2. Mark all updates

...and it's there!  What?  I just did that on the command line.  How can there be stuff that need updating?

Comment: If you did the commands in the order that you write it, then it's normal. You upgraded before updating the cache.

Answer (score 4):

Two possible reasons that could both apply:

- Your `upgrade`-`update` are in the wrong order for starters. You need to `update` first because it's this that updates your local available-packages list which `upgrade` reads.
- `upgrade` won't install upgrades if that involves adding or removing packages (which many of the kernel updates involve). You need `dist-upgrade`. "Mark all upgrades" in Synaptic is equivalent to `dist-upgrade`.

So if you ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You should find that Synaptic doesn't have anything to do.

Answer (score 2):

You took the steps in the wrong order (or mistyped them).

The correct procedure is:

1. `apt-get update` so the database fetches the last available information and versions
2. `apt-get upgrade` now you are downloading and installing packages
3. `apt-get check` if you want, I often feel comfortable just with steps 1 and 2

What seems to be happening is that you upgrade your system with old information, so maybe nothing gets really upgraded, then you update your database and when you ask Synaptic, it just tells it found new packages (due to the `apt-get update` you just ran).

PS: Keep in mind to use `sudo` if you are not root.

Answer (score 1):

Because you run first `sudo apt-get upgrade` that will update all outdated packages on your computer, then next you run `sudo apt-get update` which downloads the latest repository list. So there were already new packages in the list, packages detected by synaptic when you run it.

You should update first your repository before you upgrade so that apt will know the up-to-date packages from the net. It must be `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.